# Cocoapods requires user to import header?

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, reactive-cocoa

I see a demo using some class(RACCommand) without importing header file. It just

```
pod install
```

And then

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@property(nonatomic,strong)RACCommand *fetchHotReplyCommand;
```

It works!
However, when I tried to copy his code, I need to import RACCommand.h.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "RACCommand.h"

@property(nonatomic,strong)RACCommand *fetchHotReplyCommand;
```

How does the demo work without importing the header?

Comment: Any precompiled header in your project ? The import lines might be there.

Comment: It might be the .pch file

Comment: might be using either pch or `prefix_header_content` in their podspec